# Excel - Filter a column by other column's value

Tags: excel, filtering

Couldn't find this simple filtering option :/
What I need is to filter column A by column C values, for example:

Header | Header

Dell   | Mob
Dell   | Web
Dell   | Des
Cell   | Web
Cell   | Des
Gell   | Mob

If I'll filter column A by value "Mob" of column B, I want to get:
(All Column A values that include Mob in column B)

Header | Header

Dell   | Mob
Dell   | Web
Dell   | Des
Gell   | Mob

Thanks alot for you help!

Comment: Is it OK to use VBA in your sheet? with VBA this is easy.

Comment: And if VBA is ok, do you wish to hide the filtered lines or make a copy of the filtered table somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VBA:

- Define the Name of your filter cell as filterBy (the cell that contains the text you wish to search in col B)
- Define the Name of Column A header cell as colA
- Paste this in your sheet´s VBA code

  ```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'this checks if FilterBy was changed
    If (Not Intersect(Target, [FilterBy]) Is Nothing) Then Call DoTheFilterThing
  End Sub

  Sub DoTheFilterThing()
    Dim row_Offset As Integer
    Dim filters() As String
    ReDim filters(0 To 0)

      row_Offset = 1

      'Scan the B column and create a list of allowed A values
      'Note: this will populate the list until an empty value in A column is found
      Do While [colA].Offset(row_Offset, 0) <> ""
          If [colA].Offset(row_Offset, 1) = [FilterBy] Then
              filters(UBound(filters)) = [colA].Offset(row_Offset, 0)
              ReDim Preserve filters(0 To UBound(filters) + 1)
          End If
          row_Offset = row_Offset + 1
      Loop

      'Now apply the filter
      Range([colA], [colA].Offset(row_Offset - 1, 1)).AutoFilter 1, filters, xlFilterValues, , True
  End Sub
  ```